# Cannot read properties of null (reading '0') Kendo UI Splitter

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-splitter

I am running into an error with Kendo UI Splitter, Cannot read properties of null (reading '0'), I have no idea why this is happening and can only provide a bit of code for it. Here is the code

```
switch (collapseType) {
    case "top": {
        splitter.expand("#bottom-pane");
        splitter.collapse("#top-pane");
        splitter.size("#top-pane", "0%");
        splitterPosition = "top";
    } break;

    case "bottom": {
        splitter.expand("#top-pane");
        splitter.collapse("#bottom-pane");
        splitter.size("#bottom-pane", "0");
        splitterPosition = "bottom";
    } break;

    default: {
        splitter.expand("#bottom-pane");
        splitter.expand("#top-pane");
        splitter.size("#bottom-pane", "50%");
        splitter.size("#top-pane", "48.25%");
        $('#right-pane').css('top', '0px');
        splitterPosition = "middle";
    } break;
}
```

and its blowing up in the default, at the splitter.expand("#bottom-pane");

the error that I am getting is
[image: Error]

Has anyone ran into the error or know what the issue is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [size](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/splitter/methods/size) method expects a pane and a value as parameters. The value of the new size of the pane should be defined as pixels (i.e. "200px") or as a percentage (i.e. "50%"), so I would guess that `splitter.size("#bottom-pane", "0");` is causing the issue.

`splitter.size("#bottom-pane", "0px");` should resolve it.

Comment: it blows up on the bottom-pane expand

Comment: Well, the above logic [seems to work](https://dojo.telerik.com/iROWusEG), so I'm not really sure what the actual issue is.